# Окончание в инфинитиве (неопределенной форме глагола)

Tags: морфология, окончания, суффиксы, инфинитив

5 класс обычной общеобразовательной школы, изучают морфологический разбор глагола, в том числе инфинитива.
В слове "сделАть" выделяют "А" как окончание, "ТЬ" как суффикс.
Что-то изменилось в русском языке и я пропустила новые веяния?

В начальной школе был другой педагог русского языка, слово "сделать" разбирали по составу так:
"с-дел-А-ТЬ", причем А и ТЬ - это два суффикса (ТЬ формообразующий). Если глагол поставить в форму прошедшего времени "с-дел-а-л-А", то окончанием всегда была вторая "А".

Что такое все-таки "А" в глаголе "сделАть"?

Answer (score 0):

> Что такое все-таки "А" в глаголе "сделАть"?

Это тематическая гласная. Не морфема (не окончание, не какой-либо другой суффикс), а некоторый сегмент без значения.

> В слове "сделАть" выделяют "А" как окончание, "ТЬ" как суффикс.

Это очень странно и некрасиво. Окончание – словоизменительный суффикс, который отвечает за разные грамматические категории (род, падеж, число). -а-, как я уже написал выше, ни за что из грамматических категорий в *сделать* не отвечает.

> "с-дел-А-ТЬ", причем А и ТЬ - это два суффикса (ТЬ формообразующий)

Это вот более традиционно и менее вопиюще, хотя, конечно, последовательней бы было считать -ть- окончанием. (Выделение здесь незначимого -а- в качестве суффикса – морфемы – издержка такого подхода, с которой в идеале тоже нужно бороться.)

Answer (score 0):

1. **Ответ на вопрос**

У меня есть учебные пособия для начальной школы и для 5 — 9 класса (2013 — 2018 годов), там  разбор делается так:

**с/дел/а/**ть**, с/дел/а/**л**/а**

где А — глагольный **суффикс,** ТЬ и Л  — формообразующие **суффиксы**, причем ТЬ — показатель инфинитива, Л — показатель прошедшего времени, морфема А в прошедшем времени (после суффикса Л) — **окончание**, выражает грамматические значения ед.ч. и ж.р. в форме прошедшего времени.

Формообразующие суффиксы ТЬ и Л  **в основу не входят.**

Так что в начальной школе делался разбор, общепринятый сейчас. Мне он представляется вполне логичным. Окончанием может быть только изменяемая часть слова, выражающая непостоянные грамматические значения.

2. **Что можно сказать о суффиксе А?**

Его называют **глагольным суффиксом** и при разборе выделяют как суффикс. От других суффиксов он отличается тем, что **не участвует в словообразовании,** так как глаголы в этом случае являются непроизводными  (например, *читать*).

В то же время при образовании других слов основа глагола  **может усекаться на глагольный суффикс:** чит/а/ть – чт/ени/е.  Также глагольный суффикс усекается в личных формах некоторых глаголов: вид/е/ть – вид/ит.

Иногда глагольный суффикс называют **тематическим.** На письме важно контролировать его **наличие или отсутствие** в различных формах глагола, а также в причастиях и деепричастиях.

3. **О терминологии**

**Почему неопределенная форма глагола называется инфинитивом**
[https://lexicography.online/etymology/и/инфинитив](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%B8/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2)

Инфинити́в. Заимств. во второй половине XIX в. из ученой латыни, где infinitivus (modus) «**неопределенное (наклонение**)» — суф. производное от infinitum (< in «не» и finire «кончать») «неограниченный, неопределенный» (см. финиш). Наклонение названо было неопределенным, т. е. неясным потому, что по сравнению с изъявительным не «определено» (не имеет) с точки зрения лица и числа.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЯ ОТ 06.04.2022**

1. [Мнение Грамоты.ру:  Окончание или суффикс](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81)

**Нет единого мнения**

В лингвистике нет единой позиции по этому поводу. Многие уважаемые языковеды считают *ть* суффиксом и убедительно доказывают свою точку зрения. Другие считают *ть* окончанием и тоже приводят доводы, с которыми трудно поспорить. Поэтому разные трактовки в учебниках — в зависимости от позиции их авторов.

**Один из ответов**

Вопрос № 210215.     В слове читать корень чит-, а -ать — это окончание или суффикс???
Ответ справочной службы русского языка: Суффикс *а* и суффикс *ть*.

2. **Из учебника Литневской**:  http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part2.htm
   в разделе: Часть. 2. Морфемика и словообразование

В глаголе представлены следующие **формообразующие суффиксы:**

(1) **инфинитив** образуется **формообразующими суффиксами** -ть / -ти: чита-ть, нес-ти. У инфинитивов на -чь возможны два пути выделения флексии: пе-чь или печь, с нулевым формообразующим суффиксом (исторически в чь наложились конец основы и собственно инфинитивный показатель).

В 1 и 3 учебных комплексах показатель инфинитива описывается как **окончание.** Это связано с тем, что в этих комплексах, в отличие от комплекса 2, не вводится понятие **формообразующего суффикса**, а основой считается **часть слова без окончания**, поэтому для исключения показателя инфинитива из основы ему придан статус окончания.

Это **неверно**, поскольку показатель инфинитива не имеет обязательных для окончания **грамматических значений** рода, числа, лица или падежа и указывает только на инфинитив — неизменяемую глагольную форму.

**Примечание**: Учебный комплекс — совокупность учебных пособий для конкретного этапа обучения.

(2) **прошедшее время** изъявительного наклонения образуется суффиксами -л- (дела-л- ) и -Æ-: нёс-Æ-  — ср.: нес-л-а.

3. **Две основы глаголов**

**В вузовской практике** в глаголах, в отличие от других частей речи, выделяется не одна, а две основы:

(1) Основа **инфинитива** и обычно совпадающая с ним основа **прошедшего времени**.

Например: ВИДЕТЬ – ВИДЕЛ, основу инфинитива и прошедшего времени  глагола "видеть" составляет корень ВИД и суффикс Е; ЧИТАТЬ – ЧИТАЛ, основу инфинитива и прошедшего времени  глагола "читать" составляет корень ЧИТ и суффикс А.

Таким образом, в основу инфинитива и прошедшего времени глагольный суффикс входит обязательно.

(2) Основа **настоящего времени**.

Например: ВИЖУ, ВИДИТ, основу настоящего времени глагола "видеть" составляет только корень ВИД/ВИЖ; ЧИТАТЬ – ЧИТАЕТ, основу настоящего времени глагола "читать" составляет корень ЧИТ и суффикс А (суффикс А в основе сохраняется). Иногда такие основы называют "**неусекаемыми**".

Мы видим, что в основе настоящего времени глагольный суффикс может отсутствовать (основы бывают усекаемые и неусекаемые).

Comment: С чего бы в ФИНИТНОЙ форме быть показателю ИНфинитива? Это как?

Comment: Пожалуйста, посмотрите дополнительный материал к ответу.  Там  объясняется происхождение термина "инфинитив".

Comment: Спасибо, правда, не понимаю, к чему вы привели происхождение термина инфинитив. Так откуда в финитной форме показатель инфинитива?

Comment: Я минусовал ваш ответ, потому что он содержит лингвистическую ошибку – нахождение показателя инфинитива в финитной форме глагола. Это ошибка и в первом, и в любом другом классе. Не спорю, что _-ть_ по-разному в школе называют, – ну и пусть, это не криминально, но вопрос не об этом.